# How to automatically create arrays in MQL5?

Tags: arrays, performance, loops, arraylist, mql5

Im trying to create a list of one dimension arrays in MQL5, giving them different names/identifiers.
I tried with CArray but it just adds the array on top of another and I want to make a list of 1D arrays.

I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Already solved. Thank you!